# Current page url not giving the entire url

Tags: apex

In the debug logs, I see that
  system.debug('string main' +strmain); is returning /apex/sendinvce?inline=1
instead of giving entire URL, On UI I see the Id in the URL though
Since the ID is missing, the process is failing

```
global with sharing class SendController {
    private final ApexPages.StandardController stdCon;
        private final Order__c invce;
        private final Product2 product;
        private List<String> invceFields;
        private List<String> productfields;
        public List <Order_Line__c> OrderLineList {get; set;}
        public List <Product2> ProductLineList {get; set;}
        public Group__c Group { get; private set; }
        public Decimal FilteredSubTotal {get; set;} 
        public Decimal FilteredTotal {get; set;}
        public static string strmain{get;set;} 
        public static string strinvceid{get;set;}  
        public Boolean isPreview{get;private set;}    

         public SendController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCon) {
            Integer SelectedMonth;
            Integer SelectedYear;
            this.stdCon = stdCon;
             String SalesordrId;

            strmain = ApexPages.currentPage().getURL();

             system.debug('string main' +strmain);

            isPreview = getIsPreviewMode();

            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                invceFields = new List<String>();

  String SelectedPage = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('retURL');

     system.debug('selected---->' +SelectedPage);
    String InvID = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('Id');
     system.debug('id---->'+InvID);
    strinvceid = InveID;

     system.debug('Invce ID listed---->'+InvceID);
```

Comment: This is the actual URl that I see in the UI c.cs60.visual.force.com/apex/… but in the get URL I receive it as /apex/sendinvce?inline=1 –

Answer (score 0):

That is a normal behaviour getUrl() returns a relative URL [(look at the documentation here)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_getUrl.htm)

If you want an absolute URL, you need to get the base URL like this:

`String baseURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
strmain = baseURL + ApexPages.currentPage().getURL();`

Comment: This is the actual URl that I see in the UI https://c.cs60.visual.force.com/apex/sendinvce?preview_mode=true&Id=a180a0000002dub but in the get URL I receive it as   /apex/sendinvce?inline=1